# fastest way to distribute a quantity to elements of an array such that the difference of pairs is minimal?

Tags: algorithm

given an array of numbers *arr* and an integer *x*, distribute *x* such that the difference between any pairs is minimum possible.

e.g. *arr* = [4,2,0] and *x* = 10;

the answer should be [6,5,5];

it is obligatory to use all of *x*.

Comment: so far what i came up is to first find the minimum number than increase it one by one in a loop, but that approach is too much time consuming

Comment: Are you to minimize the maximum difference of *any* pair or only of *adjacent* pairs?

Comment: Where is this problem from?

Comment: I didn't expect it but my idea seems between two and seven times faster than don't talk just code's for a [significant range of inputs](https://ideone.com/X6GxFD).

Answer (score 2):

Compute the final mean as `(sum(arr) + x) / len(arr)`. That would be the ideal target for all numbers *if* we could also *decrease*.

The rounded down quotient tells us the minimum every number shall become, and the remainder tells us how many numbers shall get an additional 1 added. Do that after eliminating numbers already too large.

Total time O(n log n).

Python implementation:

```
def distribute(arr, x):
    total = sum(arr) + x
    I = sorted(range(len(arr)), key=arr.__getitem__)
    while I:
        minimum, additional = divmod(total, len(I))
        if arr[I[-1]] <= minimum:
            break
        total -= arr[I.pop()]
    for i in sorted(I):
        arr[i] = minimum
        if additional > 0:
            arr[i] += 1
            additional -= 1
```

Results from testing some hardcoded inputs, larger random inputs, and exhaustive small inputs:

```
433103 tests passed
0 tests failed
```

Full code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVTBjtowEL3nK0bqgbgbUNguUnfV9NQeOLWqelshZPAErE3syDY0qNpvp2M7JITiS5J59rw3zzNpTm6v1afPjTmfS6NrMFwJesi60cbBdq/lFm0SIOnQOK0re0Ebo8Vh65JEYAlCWmfk5uAw5cZk0LKXBGg57XgFBdhD7QEGD9AGYOmDlAZFSqQ7TCtUYQfL4A1PBb3O1usdOuKt12sWDv3ZywphGVP7VUsl60OdARdCOqlVIBPyWGuRBu4MfOIlY/0ZWQIlf12@TuerFXwpLkmGrH5tDPK3PhLLmBbx5KzRTcpWAS21AQlSXYpZsiGP3yxX0DOMJAyCv0I@5u7OPRQwH8eHM1OPBecVl8cb072mtdcUnW1vJHlrpRLYpqQret6RJQ23FgUpLjk57V/yyOLQujEJtg1uHQRLZlvdnNJocdQTUb87BA3aQ3Vn81XbxC39iV2lN1RnFJR1epLOvEu6olMx1NcV0FuHlcUB7aoaGdsYqVw6idDLhN0A5eQvaSbltN7vob0Pd9G@8P9RliQf4Df5aiEM2I@fGdRIrawEfONHKZJg@utTBo8Z5KsM5jkbxZ6fb@OPOX0tfCSDxQAS0a842RU3OzThOmmuqU/aoU/meZ53lxtL7uY/7WE/m4V/xtm@6glP8b3d84N1dP1ga15VIx418Cyu2tQTEdD9S3omIjLYIHeFGjcvqapkpB38vKlDwUdf9XimxmL7@4n98h6Fdt1DN9XjsS0uePyasPP5Hw)):

```
from random import choices
from itertools import product

def distribute(arr, x):
    total = sum(arr) + x
    I = sorted(range(len(arr)), key=arr.__getitem__)
    while I:
        minimum, additional = divmod(total, len(I))
        if arr[I[-1]] <= minimum:
            break
        total -= arr[I.pop()]
    for i in sorted(I):
        arr[i] = minimum
        if additional > 0:
            arr[i] += 1
            additional -= 1

def naive(arr, x):
    for _ in range(x):
        arr[arr.index(min(arr))] += 1

passed = failed = 0

def test(arr, x):
    expect = arr.copy()
    naive(expect, x)
    result = arr.copy()
    distribute(result, x)
    global passed, failed
    if result == expect:
        passed += 1
    else:
        failed += 1
        print('failed:')
        print(f'{arr =    }')
        print(f'{expect = }')
        print(f'{result = }')
        print()

# Tests from OP, me, and David
test([4, 2, 0], 10)
test([4, 2, 99, 0], 10)
test([20, 15, 10, 5, 0], 10)

# Random larger tests
for x in range(1000):
    arr = choices(range(100), k=100)
    test(arr, x)

# Exhaustive smaller tests
for n in range(5):
    for arr in product(range(10), repeat=n):
        arr = list(arr)
        for x in range(n * 10):
            test(arr, x)

print(f'{passed} tests passed')
print(f'{failed} tests failed')
```

Comment: At input length 3,000,000, range 2^64, my code output on tio.run Python 3 was 4.9 seconds and this code's was 6.6 seconds. At input length 10,000,000, range 2^32, my code output 7.65 seconds and this code exceeded the 60 second time limit. I used the code from https://ideone.com/X6GxFD, commenting out each of the calls in turn (the link from tio.run is too long for this comment input).

Comment: At input length 1,000,000, range 2^64, my code output on tio.run Python 3 (pypy) was 1.19 seconds and this code's was 3.20 seconds. (See link to code in the comment above this one. `n` is length,  `m` is range.)

Answer (score 1):

For large inputs with smaller range, it can be more efficient to binary search the target minimum. I didn't expect it, but apparently this solution can be up to seven times faster than don't talk just code's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69417522/2034787) even for medium size ranges. Here's an example with range 20 (seven times faster), and one with 100,000,000 (two times faster): https://ideone.com/X6GxFD. As we increase input length, this answer seems to be significantly faster even for the full 64 bit range.

Python code:

```py
def f(A, x):
  smallest = min(A)
 
  lo = smallest
  hi = smallest + x
 
  while lo < hi:
    mid = lo + (hi - lo) // 2
 
    can_reach = True
    temp = x
 
    for a in A:
      if a <= mid:
        diff = mid - a
        if diff > temp:
          can_reach = False
          break
        else:
          temp -= diff
 
    if can_reach:
      lo = mid + 1
    else:
      hi = mid
 
  target = lo - 1
 
  for i, a in enumerate(A):
    if a < target:
      x -= target - a
      A[i] = target
 
  if x:
    for i, a in enumerate(A):
      if a == target:
        A[i] += 1
        x -= 1
        if x == 0:
          break
 
  return A
```

Comment: You measured with a very tiny `x`, though. Might've even been zero. Can't tell what it was, as it's not printed. I think a significantly larger `x` would be more appropriate.

Comment: I mean, you use a million numbers, and you're increasing at most 20 of them. Seems rather unrealistic. Your initial `hi` btw seems unnecessarily large, could also be `hi = (sum(A) + x) // len(A) + 1` (maybe off-by-one, didn't read your binary search). Then a more appropriate much larger `x` wouldn't increase your initial `hi` much. It might even be *smaller* then.

Comment: Hmm, then again... a large initial `hi` and thus a large `mid` doesn't hurt you much anyway, as that leads to large `diff` values and thus an early `break` in the reachability test.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode I updated the ideone example to two: one with m = 20 (seven times faster), and one with m = 100,000,000 (two times faster).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that can beat both my binary search answer, as well as don't talk just code's answer at some larger input lengths. The idea is to sort the array and find the largest minimum by accumulation, traversing from smaller to larger, with O(1) space for the latter, avoiding pop operations.

[Test link](https://tio.run/##jVVNb9swDL3rVwg9WY2TOumwQ1AX8GVA7rsFRuDGSiLUsgNF3txfn1GkFMv92CYUjSSKj@TTo3x@s6eufbxelT53xnKrtGR@bqq27jRjrJYHXquLNeqltzKpjEn5INaMw7CdrRqe80uvnUHwGR/QsHGbACPrBICOMmlkiydEyl/lWw7TxW53lFZZqXc7gU6/T6qRfEPQbmjVKt3rlFd1razqWgxWq1@6qxOMnXIHvBHi5qMOHMC3m@18WZb8KQ8gI6obL0ZWr7cdKmOek@fi3J0TUaL10BmuuGpDMRsx4rjDquS3CJMUxoSfeTaN7f1mOV9O90efubMh84ekCHRfdNU08mIpYlIIBptN55j2FlifVLTG62CBWDj6BHZKRqsaDsLWjCfgM4ep4A8PfMXQvK/aHVC0P8Ghn6aXdNtSn2E9sBs1laOmCOW5uonxeqy4VocDZlxDkCrmCC3PiBoTFIf@UTUXyb66NgnG2BPzm@cITDlClBtcOImMuXRmnv8YBukDo3O3lQGBEktzdx9eDimVLdteS1NBSxReFFS/9wuIg8vIQ40EFKQc2nfI4DusR8l9GcNHyfN3YTzkRFQD6SiifHCOEzkGRuHPSNsbuE7f88dIeZ91cxF6uan0Sw3prjEFVGV4F9xjsO/61rHoEtn3xsC02F62Wek6rJWylk6JGXrtoAf8Qg7WVDhnURtS@CW1PWRApXiNOVgFTT/HOGi54VMW96QNz4Y3PueUb6AFI6djNtP3BoHCcxPqzNh7fUaVqrJkk1eG4tIxTAtvjUQQZfKfeXykh0wEEjjJKaMZoQYGCHt9EyWdjUTkg3sdTUXSAuhjhoNpmK/u779/YyAxyMQm9P1Y0E8igHotWAHGbWRxB7MULFjCbiyhhfe3WDoCF/vu/JaA6ypesbu7O2Yz10LwzVq4f7AbfaZQu@xsXIToCGjDZgK9P7rDW7v8q9snPtAlq3/4kMX3T7EUrgfDaiXE9foH).

Python code:

```py
def g(A, x):
  s = sorted(range(len(A)), key=lambda i: A[i])

  total = x
  count = 1
  curr = A[s[0]]
  to_add = 0
  extra = 0

  for i in range(1, len(A)):
    diff = A[s[i]] - curr
    needed = count * diff
    if needed >= total:
      break
    curr = A[s[i]]
    total -= needed
    count += 1

  if total:
    extra, to_add = divmod(total, count)
  
  for i in range(count):
    A[s[i]] = curr + extra
    if to_add:
      A[s[i]] += 1
      to_add -= 1
  
  return A
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the position of unchanged values does *not* need to be preserved:

0. convert into a min heap ("heapify", O(n))
1. repeat pop&count minimal values from the heap until
   - empty: distribute rest: done -or-
   - top is greater:

   - If there's not enough left to make all minimums equal top, distribute rest: done
   - else decrease rest and continue 1.

O(n+#increased_values*log(n))
Final write back of increased values left as an exercise (for now).

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you are to minimize the maximum difference between *any* pair of numbers, then this is the general approach:

1. Sort the numbers
2. Find the lowest number(s)
3. If there are Y lowest numbers, then decrement X by Y and add 1 to each of the lowest numbers until either X runs out, or the lowest numbers become equal to the next lowest numbers,
4. If X is used up then exit.
5. If not then got to step #2 and repeat.

Obviously, you can improve step #3 with a little bit of math.

Comment: Alright, posted mine. It's O(n) while I think yours is O(n^2) even after the improvement if I understand it correctly, if I give you `arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, ..., n]`.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode Looks like you're sorting which is minimum `O(n log n)`.  I'm sorting too, and my non-sorting section shouldn't be greater than `O(x)`.

Comment: Yes, O(n) was for my original, now fixed after David showed it was wrong.

Comment: Please see my answer. I reference code tests that run up to seven times faster than don't talk just code's for many input ranges, especially as input length is increased. (See also the comments under their answer.)

Comment: @גלעדברקן Yep, the way you are doing it is basically the way I would've done it: Sort, traverse ascending to find when X would be consumed, use math to find the minimum level to bring everything upto, then re-traverse allocating X until consumed (allowing for -1 allocation on remainder elements).